# BASH Comparing value (size of file) in variable to number

Tags: bash, if-statement, variables

I am trying to do a simple compare to identify if a variable is > a specific number. If yes, do one thing; if no, do another. But the comparison is not working. (Note. I am a relative newbie to bash scripting)

I have a file called eab_photos.zip. If the zipped archive is greater than 100 megs, I need to break the archive into multiple parts. (That part of the code is working correctly.)

```
echo $actual_size
if [[ $actual_size > 100 ]]
then
    echo "Big"
else
    echo "small"
fi
```

$actual_size is 21, but regardless of the comparison value (100 or 10) my code will echo "Big"

I have also tried

```
if [ $actual_size > 100 ]
```

Comment: Always quote your variables.  You should use `"$actual_size"`.  But you do not need to quote strings, and it is perfectly valid to write `echo small`.

Comment: Note that with `> 100` you have created an empty file named `100` in your directory. Remember to remove it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `[[`, the `>` operator does string comparison.  So it is a lexicographic comparison rather than numeric.  In `[`, the `>` operator is a file redirection.  Try:

```
if [ "$actual_size" -gt 100 ]; then ...
```

Comment: Or use the arithmetic conditional: `if ((actual_size > 100))`

Comment: [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) will spot this (and many other common mistakes). Strongly recommended.